# Rails Log user in after view rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, devise

I have an apply view (index page) where the user can leave his credentials if he applies from that views an account will be generated an the user will be logged in. And an overview page will be shown (create page)

But if he is already logged in and applies the sentence "we have send your password to ... cannot be shown in my view.

So I have made the following:

```
  <% unless user_signed_in? %> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns">
        <strong><%= t("apply.create.labels.password") %></strong>:
      </div>
      <div class="nine columns">
        <%= t("apply.create.labels.emailed_password_html", :link => mail_to(@user.personal_info.e_mail))%>
        <%= link_to(t("apply.create.labels.choose_password"), user_profile_path) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Try to Sign in User -->
    <% priv_sign_in %>
   <% end %>
```

This code is because. If the user applies the @user info is filled in but he can only be logged in after this part of the view is generated.

In my applycontroller create I have the following to do priv_sign_in:

```
 # Helpers
  helper_method :priv_sign_in

  # Sign in User from View
  private
  def priv_sign_in
    sign_in(@user)
  end
```

Is there any better way to do is. So in an effort to make things more clear.

When I enter the create view this has to be done:

If the user is logged in --> Hide part of view
If the user is not logged in --> Show part of view and try to log in

If it is not clear please ask some questions, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not deal with this much logic in your views.

controller :

```
@was_signed_in = user_signed_in?
sign_in(@user) unless @was_signed_in
```

View :

```
<% unless @was_signed_in %> 
  <div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
    <strong><%= t("apply.create.labels.password") %></strong>:
   </div>
   <div class="nine columns">
     <%= t("apply.create.labels.emailed_password_html", :link => mail_to(@user.personal_info.e_mail))%>
     <%= link_to(t("apply.create.labels.choose_password"), user_profile_path) %>
   </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This worked brilliant! This has given me stuff to think about. I thank you ! :)